# Graph theory with counting sets n and relations

Tags: graph-theory

For any $n$ and $k$, let $G = (V, E)$ be the graph defined as follows. The vertex
set $V = \{s \mid s \subseteq [n] \text{ and } |s| = k\}$ is the set of subsets of $[n]$ of size $k$ and the edge set
$E = \{\{u, v\} \mid u, v \in V, |u \cap v| = l \}$ is such that there is an edge between two vertices $u$ and $v$
if the size of their intersection is $l$.

(a) Give with proof the value of $|E|$. Your answer should depend on $n$, $k$, and $l$.

(b) Give with proof the number of paths of length $3$, that is, a sequence of $3$ vertices, that do
not contain repeated vertices. Your answer should depend on $n$, $k$, and $l$.

It is so hard for me to figure out with set relations and counting sets. I tried to figure out with fixed cases, but it's kinda hard to find the pattern in counting arbitrary numbers, $n$, $k$, and $l$. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: For (a), you have two sets $U$ and $V$ such that $|U|=|V|=k$, and $|U\cap V|=l$. Another way to view this is that you have some set $W$ of size $l$, and two other sets $U-W$ and $V-W$, each of size $k-l$, such that all three of these sets are disjoint. How many ways are there to choose $W$, $U-W$, and $V-W$? Note that interchanging $U$ and $V$ gives you the same edge.

For (b), you have three vertices $u$, $v$ and $w$ such that $\{u,v\}\in E$ and $\{v,w\} \in E$. Another way to view this is that you have some interior vertex $v$ and two edges incident to that vertex. Do all vertices in this graph have the same degree? If so, knowing the number of edges, what is the degree of an arbitrary vertex?